# Get the output of Column values in r?

Tags: r, string, replace

I am reading the table print from the 2nd column one by one.
This is my R code. The output of x is string and it can't retrieve the column values. I tried with 'as.factor()' and 'gsub()', but not succeeded.

```
     # Read the table .
     filename  = read.table("table.txt", row.names=1, sep="\t", header=TRUE)
     # Assigning to dataframe .
     filename <- data.frame(filename)
     # Getting the column names .
     column_name <- colnames(filename)
     print (column_name)
     # Print the name of 2nd column onwards up to end . 
     for (i in 2:length(column_name)){
          print (column_name[i]);
          ## Here , I want to parse the filename with column name ?
          ## For example table has columns "MONTH", "Pressure", "Temp".
          ## O/P:  filename$Pressure ,filenameT$emp

          ############################################
          x <- paste("filename$",column_name[i],sep="");
          ############################################
          print (x );
          names ( x ) <- rownames ( filename );
       }
```

For example:

```
  Month    Pressure       Temp         Wind   
   JAN       17             36           120
   FEB       10             34           110
   MAR       13             30           115
   APR       14             33           105
.......
```

O/P:

```
     17
     10
     13
     14


     36
     34
     30
     33


     120
     110
     115
     105
```

Comment: can you provide `dput` or a copy of the file `table.txt` so that we may reproduce this?

Comment: I think instead of the `x <- paste("filename$",column_name[i],sep="");` you should consider `x <- filename[colum_name[i]]`

Comment: It's quite possible that what you think are column names aren't.  What does `colnames(filename)` return?

Comment: @Akrun [x <- filename[colum_name[i]]] it doesn't work..

Comment: @ Carl Witthoft  'colnames(filename)' returns the name each column from starting to ending.

Comment: @Isaac I tried the code. It does print the columns.  I don't know what it means "doesn't work"

Comment: @ Hack-R  Sorry, I don't how to give the copy or upload of the file here.

Comment: Read the posting guidelines - we want a **small, reproducible** sample.  As instructed by Hack-R, use the command `dput(flename)` and paste the results into your question.

Comment: @Akrun it's still giving out put in string only giving column name and omiting the file name.                                                                                                                                         O/P: print (x) should be      filenmae$Pressure

Comment: @Carl Witthoft Thanks for your suggestion related to posts

Comment: if you just want to print the column names with filename$ in front (except for first column), maybe try `paste("filename$",colnames(filename)[-1],sep='')`

Comment: The currently accepted solution is very clunky. Show us `str(filename)` and maybe we can suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      x <- eval(parse(text=paste("filename","$",column_name[i],sep="")))
```

Try this ... perhaps it'll work.

Comment: Yeah but you've violated the Prime Directive (search `fortune` for a famous comment about "eval(parse())" )